# Can't read data from web service, json and titanium studio

Tags: web-services, titanium

how to work with web service, json and titanium studio. 
I can not extract the data and display it on android emulator.

Comment: What have your tried so far

Answer (score 1):

you have not provided  what code you have tried yet. You can have idea from [working with JSON data](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+JSON+Data)  if you still face any problem ,then post your code so for